# ASUS Q550lf - Ubuntu 14.10 - Screen randomly freezes

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.10, asus

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my ASUS laptop. Install was kinda rough, I had to change some settings around in BIOS to enable legacy settings but in the end I got it working.

I was having issues with my session randomly freezing, unable to move my mouse, or change anything on my screen.

**Current Driver on Geforce 745m:** GK107M [Geforce GT 745M] - NVIDIA Binary Driver - Verion 331.113 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested).

**Current Workaround:** Ctrl+Alt+F2 (Goes into Terminal session) then I can press Ctrl+Alt+F7 (which goes back to the Xorg Session)

**Alternate Workaround:** Put computer to sleep and resume session like normal.

Is there any permanent fix for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)